# Django - Edit data with formsets

Tags: python, django

I'm not at all sure where I'm going wrong, I had this working, and now it's not.  I know I'm close, but I'm new to Django and I can't quite get my head around this.

I'm trying to create a formset that allows users to edit data in the database.  This is what I have currently:

models.py

```
class Section(models.Model):
    section_document_type = models.ManyToManyField(DocumentType,
                                                   verbose_name="Document Type",
                                                   blank=True)
    name = models.CharField("Section Name",
                            max_length=240,
                            unique=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    required = models.BooleanField("mandatory section?",
                                   help_text="Please tick this box if this \
                                              section is mandatory.")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def edit_lld(request, slug):
    document = get_object_or_404(Document, slug=slug)
    SectionFormSet = modelformset_factory(Section, fields=('content', 'name'))
    formset = SectionFormSet(queryset=Section.objects.filter
                             (name__startswith=document.slug))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = SectionFormSet(request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
        return render(request, 'lld/edit_lld.html', {'formset': formset})
    else:
        formset = SectionFormSet(queryset=Section.objects.filter
                                 (name__startswith=document.slug))
        return render(request, 'lld/edit_lld.html', {'formset': formset})
```

I imagine it's to do with the `request.method == POST` section.  As I say it worked fine when I first did this, but now it's not. I feel close, but I'm missing something, I realise I don't fully understand how this fundamentally works.

EDIT:  Sorry, the error; I'm able to access the data, but it the changes I make in the text box don't save to the database.

EDIT: It looks like the error is actually in my template:

```
{% extends 'layouts/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    {% if error %}
    {{ error }}
    {% endif %}
    <h1>Edit Document</h1>
    <form method="POST" class="post-form">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ formset.management_form }}
        {% for form in formset %}
            {{ form.id }}
            <ul>
                <li>
                {{ form.content }}
                </li>
            </ul>
        {% endfor %}
        <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

When I replace the formset block above with just `{{ formset }}` it works fine.

Comment: So what happens? What do you see? What errors do you get?

Comment: I'm able to access the data, but the changes I make in the text box, to the data, don't save to the database.

Comment: are you rendering form errors in your template? have you done any basic debugging to see which branch of the code is being followed?  I suspect you may have a problem is related to limiting fields in the formset to `'content', 'name'` ...your `required` field is not null and has no default value so saving the form will fail

Comment: adding in a default, and including the other model fields doesn't help, though this has led me to pinpoint the error being in the template (see edit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to stem from a disparity between the fields stipulated in the view and those in the template.  If a field is in the view it has to be in the template otherwise the form won't save.